# Does it make sense to use HEVC instead of H.264 for encoding motion graphics?

Tags: video, video-encoding, adobe-after-effects

I can't seem to find a discussion on this, but would it make sense to encode professional video with HEVC, granted you have an Nvidia GPU? I know the format is usually used in situations where speed is more important than fidelity, but is there any way to quantify the quality difference between HEVC and other popular codecs?

I know HEVC doesn't have the same level of support as H.264, but could you possibly save time by first rendering to HEVC and then rendering that to H.264?

I'm rendering animations from After Effects with Adobe Media Encoder, by the way.

I'd be targeting services like YouTube, Vimeo, etc.

Comment: It depends on your target platform to host your videos. Are you planning to upload it on Youtube?

Comment: “I know the format is usually used in situations where speed is more important than fidelity” – ? Please expand. // Transcoding is never a good idea for quality.